# Load JS in autoptimize plugin manually

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance, pagespeed, gtmetrix

Autoptimize plugin is not combining all internal javascripts in one URL. It's merging all others rather than 2 JS files.
How to merge 1 and 2 js files (as shown in Gtmetrix screenshot) into autoptimize random URL manually?
[image: gtmetrix screenshot]

Comment: This is also named as caching. Check out WP Rocket or Autoptimize plugin. This will create one JS and CSS for your side (mergin all together)

Comment: Already using autoptimize plugin but it's not caching all js into 1 file. It is missing 2 of them, how to include them manually?

Comment: Autoptimize, as far as I remember at least, by default excludes jQuery from the minification/bundling process because bundling it with the rest of the scripts often results in scripts breaking so the plugin author decided to leave it alone. I believe there's a setting in Autoptimize to merge jQuery into the bundle, try that and see if it breaks anything on your site.

Comment: @cabrerahector: Thanks for your i advise, you are talking about jquery but 1 was jquery and 2nd one is not. Can you elaborate that why it is excluding lazysize script ? and also can i load jquery code into autoptimize .js file manually for minimizing expected issues in website?

Comment: That you'll have to ask the author of the Autoptimize plugin as (s)he's the only one who can tell you why the second script is being enqueued on your site. About your jQuery question: that'll probably be the same as having Autoptimize merge it into the bundle.

Comment: It means I should delete this question from stackoverflow because no one have solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check these settings under `WP Dashboard > Settings > Autoptimize`

[image]

The two files are most likely present in the Excluded scripts field. As pointed out by @cabrerahector in comments to your question, it advisable to leave jQuery out for proper rendering.

The second script is coming from Lazy Loading of Images.

[image]

It seems the author has excluded it from combining for a reason known to him. Your best option is to raise a support ticket at https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/autoptimize/ and ask them directly.

Important thing to note is even though these scripts are loaded separately, there load time is unusually high for a local script. I would check if the hosting is properly optimized first.